# Снос числа 7 в конец множества

Tags: python, python-3.x, множества

У меня есть пример кода:

```
print({7,8,9})
```

Вроде бы всë понятно, должно выводиться `{7,8,9}`, но почему-то интерпретатор выводит `{8,9,7}`. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: С тем, что по определению, множество никак не гарантирует сохранение исходной последовательности)

Comment: но почему тогда эта последовательность всегда одна?

Comment: Сейчас - так, а через год может быть по другому)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, имеется ввиду, если изменят хэшфункции, на которых работает сэт? Или я что-то путаю

Comment: @entithat Честно, не знаю, как оно устроено внутри, и почему именно семерка уходит в конец.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949350/7791165

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity